# jQuery media queries for responsive site

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, media

I want to create a website with 3 different jquery sliders. All the three sliders contain different pictures. I tried to use if and else but it didn't work. This is my code.

js

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if($(window).width() > 786){                
            $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
                auto: true,
                autoControls: true
            });                
        }else $(window).width() > 478){
            $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
                auto: true,
                autoControls: true
            }) ;               
        } else {
            $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
                auto: true,
                autoControls: true
            })  ;
        }
    });  
</script>
```

Html

```
<ul class="bxslider foto">
    <li><img src="img/Hoofd.jpg"/></li>
    <li><img src="img/deviceGrootMobiel.jpg"/></li>
</ul>  
<ul class="bxslider portret">
    <li><img src="img/portret.jpg"/></li>
    <li><img src="img/devicesGrootTablet.jpg"/></li>
</ul>  
<ul class="bxslider vision">
    <li><img src="img/vision.jpg"/></li>
    <li><img src="img/devicesGrootLaptop.jpg"/></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: use css media queries instead of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use else like that.

Use switch instead :

```
switch($(window).width()){
   case 786 : //your code
   break;
   case 478: //your code
   break;
   default: //your code
   break;
}
```

It will be useless because you have 3 times the same code, but the code itself will not be wrong.

Next time please RTFM.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error here:

```
}else $(window).width() > 478){
```

You need to create a new `if` check, as well as open the parentheses.  Surely your JavaScript console was telling you this.  I think you meant:

```
} else if ($(window).width() > 478) {
```

However, a few things to note:

1. All three of your conditional blocks to *exactly the same thing*, so there's no need for a conditional at all.
2. In each case you target all three of your `ul` elements.  Did you mean to target only one in each?
3. If the browser re-sizes then nothing will change because you only check the size when the page loads.

Using [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to show/hide/change elements tends to be a lot more effective than this approach.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Th eproblem with CSS media queries, I cant do {display: none} it will only remove the pictures, but it doesn't remove the jquery slider.

Comment: @JohnyEmanuels: Then you're not targeting the correct elements.  I can't determine where you made your mistake without seeing that code, though.  But I assure you that you most certainly *can* hide elements by setting their `display` value to `none`.

Comment: I have made individual scripts and gave the classes. In the media queries I gave them display: none but it didnt work.

Comment: @JohnyEmanuels: Then clearly you did something incorrectly.  `display:none` *does* "work".  If you're assuming that your code is correct and the CSS specification is broken, I'm afraid you're going to have a difficult time debugging your code.